# Casimir Force and Electric Field?

Tags: electric-fields, casimir-effect

I found the wiki article a bit misleading because I took $<\mathbf{E}>$ as an electric field... the equation in question is

$$\frac{F}{A} = -\frac{d}{da} \frac{<\mathbf{E}>}{A} = - \frac{\hbar c \pi^2}{240 a^4}.$$

Am I right in thinking this is an electric field? It's confused me a bit.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, <**E**> is not an electric field but the vacuum expectation value of the energy of the electromagnetic field. It cannot be Electric Field because that will give us a dimensionally incorrect equation.

Comment: thank you for your answer, now it makes sense. I really should have known that.

Comment: I thought it was an energy, just by elimination of the denominator and by noticing $F \cdot a = Energy$ - it was the mention of the electric field in the article which caused my confusion, but I should have realized it was an expectation value from typical notation.